# Filter rows based on max/min value in a group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
mydict = [
        {'HH': True, 'LL': False, 'High': 10, 'Low': 1},
        {'HH': False, 'LL': True, 'High': 100, 'Low': 20},
        {'HH': True, 'LL': False, 'High': 32, 'Low': 1},
        {'HH': True, 'LL': False, 'High': 30, 'Low': 1},
        {'HH': True, 'LL': False, 'High': 31, 'Low': 1},
        {'HH': False, 'LL': True, 'High': 100, 'Low': 40},
        {'HH': False, 'LL': True, 'High': 100, 'Low': 45},
        {'HH': False, 'LL': True, 'High': 100, 'Low': 42},
        {'HH': False, 'LL': True, 'High': 100, 'Low': 44},
        {'HH': True, 'LL': False, 'High': 50, 'Low': 1},
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

print(df)
```

```
      HH     LL  High  Low
0   True  False    10    1
1  False   True   100   20
2   True  False    32    1
3   True  False    30    1
4   True  False    31    1
5  False   True   100   40
6  False   True   100   45
7  False   True   100   42
8  False   True   100   44
9   True  False    50    1
```

I am trying to find peak values on a chart. So if there are several `True` or `False` values in either `HH` or `LL` I want to only leave the one with the highest `High` or lowest `Low` accordingly. I tried doing it like this:

```
check = True

while check:

    df2 = df[df.HH | df.LL]

    h1 = df2.HH & df2.HH.shift()
    h2 = df2.High < df2.High.shift()
    h3 = df2.HH & df2.HH.shift(-1)
    h4 = df2.High < df2.High.shift(-1)

    l1 = df2.LL & df2.LL.shift()
    l2 = df2.Low > df2.Low.shift()
    l3 = df2.LL & df2.LL.shift(-1)
    l4 = df2.Low > df2.Low.shift(-1)

    df3 = df2[(h1 & h2 | h3 & h4) | (l1 & l2 | l3 & l4)]

    df.loc[df.index.isin(df3.index), ["HH", "LL"]] = False

    check = not df3.empty
```

And it seems to procude desirable result on a small example dataframe:

```
      HH     LL  High  Low
0  True   False    10    1
1  False   True   100   20
2  True   False    32    1
3  False  False    30    1
4  False  False    31    1
5  False   True   100   40
6  False  False   100   45
7  False  False   100   42
8  False  False   100   44
9  True   False    50    1
```

But for a reason I am yet to figure out it still leaves occasional repeating peaks in a bigger dataframe.

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: Your selection criterion is not clear. You seem to removing all but one of repeated True-False or repeated False-True sequences but leaving sequences of True-True and False-False. This does not seem to match your explanation of the process. Also how do you decide to keep either the highest High or lowest Low if they do not occur on the same row. A clearer explanation and expected output just from your example data would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the max High and min Low are in the same row, you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
group = (df[['HH', 'LL']].ne(df[['HH', 'LL']].shift())
         .any(axis=1).cumsum()
        )

g = df.groupby(group)
m1 = g['High'].transform('max').eq(df['High'])
m2 = g['Low'].transform('min').eq(df['Low'])

df.loc[~(m1&m2), ['HH', 'LL']] = False
```

Output:

```
      HH     LL  High  Low
0   True  False    10    1
1  False   True   100   20
2   True  False    32    1
3  False  False    30    1
4  False  False    31    1
5  False   True   100   40
6  False  False   100   45
7  False  False   100   42
8  False  False   100   44
9   True  False    50    1
```

Intermediates:

```
      HH     LL  High  Low  group     m1     m2  m1&m2
0   True  False    10    1      1   True   True   True
1  False   True   100   20      2   True   True   True
2   True  False    32    1      3   True   True   True
3   True  False    30    1      4  False   True  False
4   True  False    31    1      4   True   True   True
5  False   True   100   40      5   True   True   True
6  False   True   100   45      6   True  False  False
7  False   True   100   42      6   True   True   True
8  False   True   100   44      6   True  False  False
9   True  False    50    1      7   True   True   True
```